# AndroidStartServiceOnBoot.class is called only once in the program..but i want it to call everytime

Tags: android

I want that androidStartServiceOnBoot.class should be executed every time. But it is executing only once.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    //You can do the processing here.
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

    if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
    //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
    msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
    }
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidStartServiceOnBoot.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    Toast.makeText(context, msgStr + "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
 }
```

Comment: the string that you are trying to parse is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

response that is being returned from ur php script or whatever...
is having a 
 tag attached as
 1.echo "br"  ----for php
etc....(Remove this for php)
Check ur response returning from server..There should be no 
 tag while returning response from file residing on server

Comment: My php Script..what to do with this????

<?php

$host="127.0.0.1";
$uname="root";
$pwd="";
$db="mydata";


 $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
 mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
  
 $mobile=$_REQUEST['mno'];
 
 $flag['code']=0;
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracker where mobile like '$mobile'") or die(mysql_error());
 

 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
 
 if($r=mysql_query("insert into tracker values('$mobile') ",$con))
 {
  //$flag["code"] = 1;
  $code=1;
  
 }
 }
 echo json_encode($code);
 mysql_close($con);
?>